# Arduino HTTP client not receiving full response from django server

Tags: python, django, arduino, arduino-uno

I have written an Arduino client which polls a Django webpage and reads some data from it (I am using the [Adafruit CC3300 Wifi shield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-cc3000-wifi/overview) and library). The problem I am encountering is that sometimes (not always), I won't be able to read the entire response. For example, the full response is

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2016 21:10:59 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
ETag: "-5087009845757219665"
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: OPTIONS, GET

{"track":null,"volume":100,"state":"NothingSpecial"}
```

but I will only read

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2016 21:10:59 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Py
```

This happens only for the arduino client (it works fine when I `curl` the webpage or use some other http client) so it would seem like there's something wrong with the code on the Arduino, yet I am using the [example](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-cc3000-wifi/webclient) provided by the manufacturers of the shield, and also the example is working for many other webpages I've tried.

I am using `python manage.py runserver` to run the Django page. Any clue as to what might be the problem? Perhaps it has something to do with how Django returns the response?

The code is [here](https://github.com/simon-zhu/elec291-project2), which includes both for the Arduino client as well as the Django code under branch `linux`. I should also include that I am experiencing this problem with the `playlist_status` view , aka the `/playlist/status/` endpoint, and the problem occurs with **much** higher frequency when there is a track playing versus when there is no track playing.